# Magic functions and inheritance

Tags: php, multiple-inheritance, magic-function

I would like to know if it's possible to create a magic object that extends another magic object, (with PHP).

Comment: Now where does the magic happen?

Comment: well the two classes are using magic methods

http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: @Sbm007 __get and __set are magic methods, they're called whenever you try to access a non-public member variable.

Comment: What's the point in calling your getter/setter methods __get/__set... The 2 underscores are only used by PHP for magic methods such as toString, constructor and destructor in order to avoid any naming conflicts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking... are you wanting to explicitly invoke the magic methods of the parent class? If so, you can use the class' `parent` reference:

```
class Object extends dbObj{
    // ...
    // this is what i'm assuming you're looking for:
    public function __call($method, $variables){
        return parent::__call($method, $variables);
    }
}
```